# PATINDEX in Sql 2005 with a CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

im using the PATINDEX sentence into a case sentence:

```
select Choosed1=
CASE PATINDEX('%1|%',field1)
//Here im getting an error:
WHEN >0 THEN 'X'
END
from testtable
```

How could i put the >0  condition to avoid the error?

Thanks in advance

Best Regards.

Jose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CASE
    WHEN PATINDEX('%1|%',field1) > 0 THEN 'X'
    ELSE 'Y'
END
```